# Detect keyboard deployment

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am porting an WP7 Silverlight application to the UWP Windows 10 mobile platform.
In my old code I used to check if the keyboard was deployed in the following way:

```
if (DeviceStatus.IsKeyboardDeployed)
            {
                // do stuff
            }
            else
            {
                //do stuff
            }
```

Now I want to do the same in WM10 but there does not seem to be an equivalent of this function anymore. I already checked the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.aspx)
And Googled but cannot find it.

Does anybody know if you still can detect this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of [InputPane clss](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane), for example like this:

```
InputPane pane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
pane.Showing += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"Keyboard {(s as InputPane).Visible}");
pane.Hiding += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"Keyboard {(s as InputPane).Visible}");
```

Just subscribe to *InputPane* attached to your view, you can even make a proberty in your app that will be changed in pane's *Showing/Hiding* events. Or you can just move your job to those events - this depends on your needs.

Comment: MMmmm Will try this later this day! Will let you know if it works! Thank you already for the input! :)

Comment: I am on windows form aplication. Is there something i need to do to work with InputPane? I cant declare it right now.