# How to use InputPane

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I have searched for some quick tutorial to get started with InputPane but was unsuccessfully. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670158/detect-keyboard-deployment), but i can't declare it. Can someone please provide me with just a bit of code for a windows form application to tryshow a InputPane? Or some link to a start guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't declare in UWP - just add

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
```

...

```
InputPane pane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
pane.TryShow();
```

In case if you are using WinForms you should wait for Project Cenntenial launch. Currently it's in beta phase. You will be able to convert your WinForms application to package that could be published in store. And in this case you would be able to use UWP features in .Net projects.

Comment: Cant use that using.. 
Also tried this: 
`using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Windows.UI.ViewManagement;`
`using System.Windows.UI.ViewManagement;`

Comment: Aah, you are using Winfowms. Sorry. I have thought that if windows-10, than you are using UWP